# Outlook 2007: Reading Pane is not updated when an encrypted Email is imported

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, vsto, outlook-redemption

we use Redemptiontools to develop a Addin for Outlook. At first we create Emailstubs from a Metadataset. When the User select a Mail we load a msg file from the Network and import it into the Emailstub. We dont have any problems in Outlook 2010/2013/2016.

But in Outlook 2007 the reading pane doesnt refresh if the mail has a Signature. I have deselect and reselect the Mail and then i can see the new mail.

Creating the Emailstub from an metadataset:

```
    using (ComObjectWrapper<RDOFolder> rdoFolder = RDOSession.Resource.GetFolderFromID(folderEntryID).WithComCleanup())
    {
            using (ComObjectWrapper<RDOMail> mailstub = rdoFolder.Resource.Items.Add().WithComCleanup())
            {
                    mailstub.Resource.Sent = true;
                    mailstub.Resource.SenderName = metadatamail.SenderName + " ";
                    mailstub.Resource.SenderEmailAddress = metadatamail.SenderEmailAddress + " ";
                    mailstub.Resource.SentOnBehalfOfName = metadatamail.SentOnBehalfOfName + " ";
                    mailstub.Resource.SentOnBehalfOfEmailAddress = metadatamail.SentOnBehalfOfEmailAddress + " ";
                    mailstub.Resource.Subject = metadatamail.Subject + " ";
                    mailstub.Resource.ReceivedTime = metadatamail.ReceivedTime;
                    mailstub.Resource.Body = metadatamail.Body + " ";
                    mailstub.Resource.To = metadatamail.To + " ";
                    mailstub.Resource.ReceivedByName = metadatamail.ReceivedByName + " ";
                    mailstub.Resource.UnRead = metadatamail.UnRead;
                    if (metadatamail.ContainsAttachments)
                    {
                        var Attach = mailstub.Resource.Attachments.Add(new char[0]);
                        Attach.FileName = "Attachment.txt";
                    }
                    mailstub.Resource.Save();
            }
    }
```

Importing the msg file in the selection change Event of the Explorer (expl):

```
    void expl_SelectionChange()
    {
        using (var selection = expl.Selection.WithComCleanup())
        {
            foreach (var item in selection.Resource)
            {
                if (item is Outlook.MailItem)
                {
                    string entryID = (item as Outlook.MailItem).EntryID;
                    GC.Collect();
                    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                    GC.Collect();
                    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(entryID))
                    {
                        using (var researchEntry = RDOSession.Resource.GetMessageFromID(entryID).WithComCleanup())
                        {
                            string mailpath = GetEmailFromNetwork(entryID);
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mailpath))
                            {
                                Redemption.SafeMailItem sItem = new Redemption.SafeMailItem();
                                sItem.Item = researchEntry.Resource;
                                sItem.Import(mailpath, (int)rdoSaveAsType.olMSG);
                                sItem.ReleaseComObject<Redemption.SafeMailItem>();
                                researchEntry.Resource.Save();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

RDOSession:

```
    private ComObjectWrapper<RDOSession> RDOSession
    {
        get
        {
            try
            {
                var rdoSession = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Redemption.RDOSession")) as RDOSession;
                if (rdoSession != null)
                {
                    rdoSession.MAPIOBJECT = this.Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT;
                    return rdoSession.WithComCleanup();
                }
            }
            catch { }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Does anyone have a hint or a solution?

Comment: Do you mean HTML signature? Or a security signature? Unfortunately Outlook like to keep stale data, the only reliable way to refresh the data is to deselect the message and select it again.

Comment: It is a security signature. Hmm... is there any possible way to deselect and select the message programmatically in Outlook 2007?

Comment: You can try to simulate keyboard input...